# What would the French equivalent of the name "Felix" be?

Tags: prononciation, prénoms

If an equivalent exists. Or if it doesn't, would a native French speaker find it at all difficult to pronounce the name "Felix"? If yes, is there a similar name that is more natural?

Comment: Where would you say that name is from ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Actually, it comes from Latin.

Comment: @Kareen : The thing is once we know it comes from latin, I don't really understand how French speakers would have any difficulty at pronouncing it. Hence maybe it's a lot more common elsewhere, which would be more what my question was about, *le cas échéant*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Félicien](http://tonprenom.com/felicien) came to my mind, if you really want to change it. Félix is perfectly pronouncable for French people though, and not uncommon as a first name.

According to [this page](http://guy.joly1.free.fr/latin_prenoms.html), for men, Félix and Félicien are both coming from the latin *felix*, so any of both would do.

Answer (score 4):

Felix comes from Latin, meaning "happy". Félix is the French version (~`fay-leeks` or `[feɪliks]` in English IPA).

It's a fairly common name, though according to [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9lix), more popular in Quebec than in Europe. You get [a lot of hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=f%C3%A9lix%20site%3afr.wikipedia.org) if you google it.

Comment: Well one would probably sound `fay-licks` as `['feɪ.lɪks]`, which not quite the same as `[fe.liks]` in French.

Comment: Ah, yes, my `licks` is a little off, thanks.